# NodeJS writing response

Tags: javascript, node.js, response

First of all: I am a **beginner** at **nodeJS**!

My Problem is that i have an html-file, which is complex, and i want to write an individual response in it. For example

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Listening at port 3000');
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + 'index.html');
//
// what to write here when i want to modify the index.html before sending?
//
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <div id="writehere">
    <!--I would like to modify the page here-->
    </div>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me and understood my question!

Comment: What do you mean modify it? Perhaps you need a templating language, and/or a full web framework?

Comment: I recommend you read through this http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html   some template engines with standard html are mustache and ejs

Comment: Sorry, i mean writing into :) So for example in the div "writehere" there should be another div added trough node